Is the SVM single-threaded
In my understanding, the Solana runtime creates new instances of the SVM for each transaction, due to this, I can't help but wonder if the SVM is actually single-threaded.
I know the Solana runtime can process multiple transactions in parallel but I'm wondering if the actual VM itself is single-threaded.

I think having an objective answer for this will be difficult, as actually defining what "the SVM" is and where that definition starts/ends is still a point of contention. Perhaps you could add a rough definition of what you consider to be the SVM which would make answering this easier.

I'm thinking about the actual sbpf virtual machine. I never liked the idea of referring to the entire chain as VM anyway as it leads to confusion. I mean Sui and Aptos run MoveVM does that mean we'll refer to them as MoveVMs? Ok rant over.

The SVM itself is single-threaded -- it only processes one sequence of instructions at a time. It's impossible to spawn more threads within the VM, and due to the account locking done the runtime before sending accounts to the VM, you don't need to worry about data consistency or race conditions.
